# Spark as part of a bigger python script

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am used to executing spark python scripts in a cloudera cluster where i used pyspark or spark-submit commands in order to execute them.

Now i have to make a script which does a lot of things and sometimes uses spark to get some data from HBase.

Is there a way to do this without using the cluster resources during the entire time that the script is running and only using them when the spark part is running?

Comment: Spark is meant for parallel processing, if you need it only to access HBase, you should just use standard python libs all the way

Comment: I was short in my explanation, i use it to access HBase and process the data to get a df, i do processing with spark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you are done with Spark in your script, just "stop" it to free resources:

- Either on the `SparkContext`: `sc.stop()`
- Or on the `SparkSession`: `spark.stop()` to stop the underlying `SparkContext`

Note: Once it has been stopped, you are allowed to recreate a new one:

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

Quote of `SparkContext`'s Javadoc: *"[...] Only one SparkContext may be active per JVM.  You must `stop()` the active SparkContext before creating a new one [...]"*

Comment: Can i start it again at a later time?

Comment: I invite you to accept this answer if it has helped you.